# Can the original source subvolume of a btrfs snapshot be found by examining that snapshot?

Tags: filesystems, btrfs

For example:
I have a subvolume /home and create a snapshot:
btrfs subvolume snapshot /home /temp/snapshot

Is there any connection, that tells me that the new subvolume /temp/snapshot was originally cloned from /home?

In other words: If I delete everything in /temp/snapshot and create a new empty subvolume /temp/snapshot2, are these subvolume of different "types" whatsoever?

Comment: Emmanuels answer is true - but only if the original subvolume still exists. The conclusion answers the second question: There are two different types of snapshots: Those with given Parent UUIDs and those without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your first question is yes. Not only can you determine the source subvolume of a snapshot, you can also see the snapshots for a given subvolume.

For example if you run: `btrfs subvol show /temp/snapshot` you'll see something like this:

```
MOUNT_POINT/temp/snapshot
        Name:                   snapshot
        UUID:                   862e55f5-d1a0-4742-87ed-b430dd181a97
        Parent UUID:            5c1e9a70-3158-6940-94d4-be82e064f8df
        Received UUID:          -
        Creation time:          2017-01-26 22:34:21 -0500
        Subvolume ID:           940
        Generation:             29824
        Gen at creation:        29824
        Parent ID:              5
        Top level ID:           5
        Flags:                  readonly
        Snapshot(s):
```

If that snapshot itself is the source of other snapshots, you'd see them listed under *snapshot(s)*.

The *Parent UUID* is the source subvolume, which you can use with `btrfs subvol list` and `grep` to get more information about the source subvolume:

```
$ btrfs subvol list -u . | grep 5c1e9a70-3158-6940-94d4-be82e064f8df
ID 878 gen 29824 top level 5 uuid 5c1e9a70-3158-6940-94d4-be82e064f8df path home
```